# How to include all sub-commands help message in argparse's help messages?

Tags: python, argparse

I would like `--help` generated by `argparse` to include help for all sub-commands.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working, although it's not very elegant.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
print_help_fn = parser.print_help
sub_parsers = [
   # define sub-parsers here.
]
def print_help_wrapper():
    print_help_fn()
    for s in sub_parsers:
        print("Subcommand:")
        s.print_help()

parser.print_help = print_help_wrapper

parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help')
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: you found all the relevant pieces. `print_help` uses `format_help` if you want to collect and join the strings before printing.

Comment: Overwriting the print_help function feels fragile, it only happens to work if it's done before `parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help')`

Comment: The `_HelpAction` class `__call__` has a `parser.print_help()` call.  So if you want that to use the new version, it has to be initialized after.  An alternative to is define your own `help action` subclass.  Anyways, the subparsers mechanism is relatively 'shallow', implemented almost entirely in the `_SubParsersAction` class.  Other than than that, the main parser "knows" next to nothing about subparsers.

Comment: When I've seen discussions like this, the focus was on making a composite help for documentation purposes, not on replacing the default helps.